# How can I configure jest tests to use nuxt-env

Tags: jestjs, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt-env to access my env variables in vue-components and jest to test the components. But for the tests this.$env is undefined. Is there a way to configure jest to use the nuxt-env variables?

my nuxt.config.js :

```
['nuxt-env', { // Environment variables for runtime
  keys: [
    'FOO'
  ]
}],
```

the usage in vue components:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      bar: this.$env.FOO
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Currently the jest-test for the component returns the following error:

*Error: [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'FOO' of undefined"*